# Alias for viewing logs with todays date

Tags: alias, .bash-profile

I want to create an alias:

alias readFile='ls file1.todaysdate' where todaysdate is in format 130714.

How would i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the date command to give you the date in that format:

```
date +%y%m%d
```

this gives you the YYMMDD format.
In the alias file you can drop that date format into your command with the `` back-ticks like so:

```
alias readFile='ls file1.`date +%y%m%d`'
```

everything between the back-ticks is executed and the output is placed instead of the back-ticks. so

```
echo "hello `whoami`"
```

would say "hello " followed by your username.

Comment: Another form of the command substitution (_backtics_) is `$(command)`. The latter variant is better suitable for nesting.

Comment: i tried $(command) and that works as well